# Laravel pivot sync() attaches wrong values

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

I've been dealing with this issue on almost every sync() to the pivot tables where, in Laravel 5.6, when I perform the following it adds one row that is non existent in the request:

```php
$firm_data = request()->all(); // get the request data
$firm = Firm::where('id', request('firm_id')); // get the Firm model
$firm->update($firm_data); // update the model

// add the firm address with a belongsToMany() relationship set on Models\Firm and on Models\Address
$address = $firm->with('addresses')->first();
$addresses = request('addresses'); // get the request data for address
$address->update($addresses); // all ok till here

// deal with the pivot table
// here's the issue...
$address->cities()->sync([request('firm_id'), $addresses['city_id']]);
```

The firm data and the address data state is saved correctly in the DB, although, the pivot table is filled with two columns instead of one.

I have, in the whole request, one only `city_id = 3034856` but **to the pivot table it is added the first row** firm_id = 1, city_id = 1, "**which comes from nowhere**":

The pivot table - firm_city

`+---------+---------+
 | firm_id | city_id |
 +---------+---------+
 |       1 |       1 |
 |       1 | 3034856 |
 +---------+---------+`

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Just to make sure it's right, here the methods for each model Firm and Address:

```php
// On the Firm model
public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(City::class, 'firm_city');
}

// on the City model
public function firms()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(Firm::class, 'firm_city');
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight on why this might be happening,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `firm_id`:

```php
$address->cities()->sync([$addresses['city_id']]);
```

Eloquent gets the `firm_id` from `$address`, you don't have to specify it.
If you specify 
it, Eloquent assumes that you want to sync a `City` with `id=1`.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonas, both for the answer and for the edit. It works fine now. I was getting crazy with this. Thank you! :)